# SIP call using Peers Java API

Tags: java, sip

I am using java SIP library (http://peers.sourceforge.net/) to implement SIP call in my application. I am looking an option by which i can handle my GUI state on the basis of events which generate when user invite other user for call until remote(other user) don't accept a call.

I have seen calleepickup:

```
@Override
public void calleePickup(SipResponse sipResponse)
```

This event trigger when call accept/reject dialog appear on remote side however i was assuming this when exactly a remote accept a call.

Same as ringing event is not invoke in any case either i dial or receive a call from remote.

```
@Override
public void ringing(SipResponse sipResponse)
```

Any idea how i can add this functionality to handle my dialup GUI.

Comment: Needs more specifics. Exactly what do you want to happen and when? How is the GUI affected?

Comment: Let say user1 invite for a SIP call to user2. Call started but still user2 don't answer the call so call is in ringing state on both side. I want that during this state from a caller side i get some kind of event until user2 don't answer a call.

Comment: Events typically indicate a state change, not that a state remains unchanged. I'd have thought you'd want an event to indicate that user2 failed to answer the call, not an event that keeps on firing until that happens. So what am I missing here?

Comment: Well there are two state: Ringing and Accept/Reject call. In API SIPListener interface have calleePickup() method which is representing Ringing state and remoteHangup() when call reject by remote. What i am looking a Call Accept event handling.

Comment: Ok, there are a number of responses that you can get. Looks like the one you want is 200 OK to indicate that the call was accepted. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SIP_response_codes

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, but 200 OK can't represent as a call pickup state response. It is mentioned and i also observed this after every action i get a successful response even when call is ringing response will be 200 OK.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/ymartineau/peers/blob/master/peers-gui/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/peers/gui/EventManager.java

There are methods for all events (incoming call, callee pickup, call rejected, etc). You should manage your own state machine to handle events.

Comment: I get idea from EventManger and now trying to implement a new event when exactly callee "answer the call". As i mentioned in above comment "callee pickup" method trigger when call dialog box appear in callee side not exactly when callee answer a call. Also "ringing" method is not working in any case.

Comment: No calleepickup really matches the reception of 200 ok. If you have a server in between that answers before, this the server prblem, not peers problem